# Display loader while waiting for Ajax response, then fade out the loader and fade in the response no jQuery

Tags: javascript

I am using a regular XMLHttpRequest and I want to display a loading element while waiting for the response and then display the response with an animation.

I was able to do this with jQuery, but I have found no answers for vanilla JS.

Here is the relevant code.

```
<div id="loader"></div>
<div id="demo" class="animate-bottom">
ooo
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Get the AJAX data</button>
```

The Css is not necessary, the loader is set to opacity 0.3(to see what is happening) and the

The JS

```
var output = ''; // the variable to hold the parsed response
function loadDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {


// so far ok, the trouble starts here, setting the loader to opacity 1
  document.getElementById("loader").style.opacity = 1;
  var theResponse = this.responseText;
  var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(theResponse); 
  // the looping through the data
  for (i=0; i < parsedResponse.length; i++ ) {
  output += '<li>' + parsedResponse[i].title +'</li>' + '<img src=' + 
  parsedResponse[i].thumbnailUrl + '/>'  + '<span>' + parsedResponse[i].url 
  + '</span>';
  };
  // here the response goes to the demo div.
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = output;
  }
  // these 2 lines do not work as desired
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos", true);
  xhttp.send();
   }
```

I know, this is an asynchronous request and the problem lies there.

What is happening now, the demo div is animated to the screen as soon the button is clicked and the loader is not displayed while the data is parsed.

I am using a large data set , the request and parsing take few seconds.

Is there a way to make this work, or do I have to wrap some of the code into a setTimeout?

The codepen is here, I apologize for the time it takes to load the data(5seconds for me).

https://codepen.io/damPop/pen/gQOVEe?editors=0010

Comment: your `opacity:1` should start before `onreadytatechange`

Comment: @Sysix, tried that, but the div for the response gets displayed immediatelly, then a blank screen , then the data is loaded in.